# Defining variables outside of the 'while' loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

[Background info: I am currently completing a course on Python programming from the MIT edx site, and am working on the section on while loops.]

The question I have been struggling with is as follows: "Write a while loop that sums the values 1 through end, inclusive. end is a variable that we define for you."

When I tried answering the question, I put:

```
while end != 0:
    total = 0 + end
    end = end-1
print total
```

The return result for any value I put in for 'end' was 1, which obviously is incorrect.

However, when I tried again, I defined 'total' outside of the loop, and put:

```
total = 0
while end != 0:
    total = total + end
    end = end-1
print total
```

This works!

My question is: why does the first code that I put in not work? What is the significance of defining 'total' outside of the loop?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Short Description of Python Scoping Rules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules)

Comment: It's actually unrelated to scope. Each loop has substantively different contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first code block, each time you run `total = 0 + end`, you reset `total`

```
total = 0 + 10
total = 0 + 9
total = 0 + 8
...
total = 0 + 1
```

At the end of this, the last line run was `total = 0 + 1` which equals `1`

In the second loop, you are utilizing the previous value of `total`:

```
total = 0
total = 0 + 10
total = 10 + 9
total = 19 + 8
...
total = 54 + 1
```

With each pass through the loop, total is incremented and utilized. In the first one, you are over writing the total in each loop.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with `total = 0 + end`. What this does is assign the current value of `end` to `total`. Since `end` eventually becomes `1`, that's what total is. You need to add `end` to the running `total`:

```
total = total + end
```

or:

```
while end != 0:
    total += end
    end -= 1
print total
```

Answer (score 0):

When you define `total` inside the while loop, it reassigns itself to `0 + end` each time it loops, which is 1 by the end of the program. When you define it outside, it sets `total` to 0, then for each loop within `while`, it continues to add the value to it.

Also, sidenote, you can write `total = total + end` as `total += end` and it means the same thing but is actually a (very) small bit faster.

Answer (score 0):

In the example with `total` inside the while loop, it is being redefined each time `end != 0`, and you are printing it right after `end` was equal to 1 (`end = end-1` will make break you out of the while loop after end is equal to 1).

In the other example, you are not redefining `total` each trip through the while loop, and this is accumulating the answer you expect.